# for loop in cmd in windows gdal program

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, gdal

I am trying loop through 100's of .tif files. I used the code below in Linux. It worked.

```
for f in * ;
do gdal_translate -projwin -29.97 71.89 45.99 28.801 -of GTiff  $f subset/$f -co compress=lzw
```

However, I am unable to execute For loop in windows.  I have tried within cmd for looping `for  %i in (*)` It is showing `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

What is the solution for this?

Comment: When using the `for` loop in a batch file rather than in Command Prompt you have to double the `%`-signs. Furthermore, there is a `do` keyword that must appear in the same line as the closing `)` behind the `*`, and the following command line/block must be placed/begin in the same line too. Type `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the help text very carefully to find out how to use `for`…

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible to run in cmd without creating batch file? I tried `for  %%i in (*) do` with suggestion but still not working.

Comment: Of couse it is possible, given that you use a single `%`-sign and the looped command is in the same line: `for %i in (*) do command`

Comment: thanks for making me understand. how can I implement this in windows for specifying files and saving `$f foldername/$f`

Comment: Well, just use `%i` instead of `$f`. Did you read the output of `for /?` after all??

Comment: Note that when using `for` on the command line (instead of in a batch file) you need to double the `%` characters. It's also important to know `for` works totally different on Windows. Make sure to check the help first by opening a Command Prompt and running `FOR /?` and `FORFILES /?` as `FORFILES` may also be interesting.